# WS2811 IC Supply Current

Tags: power, led, driver, rgb, ws2811

There are ten RGB LEDs and ten [WS2811](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) ICs in my circuit. I'm trying to find out how much current the WS2811 IC draws from my 5 V supply.

No information about supply current is given in the datasheet. I've read many forum threads on this topic but couldn't understand them. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet does not list the supply current value.

However, what the datasheet does say, we might roughly approximate what it could be.

The datasheet says that supply voltage must be approximately 5V, and it shows an example circuit where VDD supply is 5V and it can be driven with 12V if you put a 2k7 resistor in series with VDD, so there will be approximately 7V over the resistor.

So with this approximation, there will approximately be 2.6mA going into the chip.

Comment: I thought the figure I found in the datasheet seemed crazy low. I removed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The LED current is between almost 0 and 17.5mA maximum for each of the three LEDs so between 0 and 52.5mA (typical maximum is 49.5mA).

The supply current of the chip is **not** specified in the datasheet. Various [actual measurements](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/fake-ws2811-ic/599551/9) by users indicate somewhere around 1-2mA typical for the entire chip.

This could be a limitation if you are expecting to operate from batteries with the LEDs controlled 'off' via the serial input(s) most of the time. Bringing the input low (to prevent sneak paths through the chip protection network) and then switching the power off with a MOSFET might be a solution. Since the outputs are allowed to exceed Vdd you may be able to just switch the supply to the WS2812(s) with a small P-channel MOSFET such as AO3401.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the current to LEDs or the chip itself?  The post above mentions the IC current, but usually the LED current is more of interest since it is much larger.  That value is in the datasheet, although they certainly try to hide it:

[image]

Note that this is per LED channel, so with all 3 pixels as 255 you will have 3 times that per chip.

Comment: Just a note that I removed my answer, so it is no longer "above" -- answers are not in a static sequence.